# What is the recommended way to destructure a nested Option?

Tags: struct, rust, option-type, destructuring

How should I go about reading the value that's nested within two `Option`s?

I have this code:

```rust
struct Person<T> {
    name: &'static str,
    preferences: Vec<&'static str>,
    variant: Option<T>,
}

struct Driver {
    seats: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let list: Vec<Person<Driver>> = todo!();

    let name = "some-name";

    // add a bunch of Person<Driver> drivers to the `list`

    let found = list.iter().find(|candidate| candidate.name == name);

    // other things
}
```

What's the cleanest or most recommended way to access the field `seats` from `Option<Person<Driver>>` in `found`?

The two ways I've done it is with a nested `if let` or a nested `match`. The nested `match` looks a little ugly, so this is what I'm going with:

```rust
if let Some(person) = found {
    if let Some(driver) = &person.variant {
        println!("{:?}", driver.seats);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of going about it?

The reason I have an `Option` field called `variant` is since I also have `Rider` structs and they're literally just a `Person`. Since both drivers and riders have almost all the same fields, I structured it this way instead of opting to say a `person: Person` field in each `Rider` and `Driver` struct which felt odd.

Comment: `if let Some(Some(x)) = ...` or other nested patterns are sometimes useful as well. Applying the duplicate to this case: `if let Some(Person { variant: Some(driver), .. }) = found`

Comment: You can also use `if let Some(driver) = found.and_then(|p| p.variant.as_ref())`

Comment: Ah @Shepmaster, your first comment destructuring the `Person` struct and then destructuring the field `variant` seems to fix it! No compile errors.

Comment: I had tried some variation of that but I don't think I got the right syntax until now! Thanks!